# SQL query that selects the last date that the value became 0

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to select the row based on the last date when the value became 0 but i cant think of what should i do... here is my sql query so far...

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1) [Date_Time]
  ,[Value1]
  ,[Status1]
  ,[Value2]
  ,[Status2]
  ,[Value3]
  ,[Status3]
  FROM TABLE NAME
  WHERE [Value1] <= 0 OR [Value2] <= 0 OR [Value3] <= 0 AND [DATE_TIME] >= [DATE_TIME]
  ORDER BY [DATE_TIME] DESC
```

Here is the sample data. As you can see the first
  value has `2.0` on the date `2018-07-26 21:00:00.000`  and
  the next data is `0` so i want to get the 2nd one `2018-07-26 22:00:00.000`
 not the 3rd one `2018-07-26 03:00:00.000`

[image: sample data here]

Comment: Looking at your query, and non-normalized structure, I would first suggest you EDIT your post and show some sample data.  Why you have 3 values in a single row probably has a better way to handle... Also if you could edit and give some context of what the query is for, we might offer better table design options for you too.

Comment: We'll need to see sample data. It's not currently possible to know if grabbing the most recent date for a `0` value is sufficient, because you asked for the date when it *became* `0`. If there are multiple dates in a row where the values are all `0`, and they did not change, then the most recent date wouldn't be *"when the value became 0"*.

Comment: share sample data and your expected output

Comment: i already edited it and show the sample data. sorry for not putting it a while ago

Comment: @Carl When *any* of the three values became `0`, or just the first one?

Comment: @TylerRoper uhm for example the new data gave a value more than 0 so its good but the next date gave a 0 value and then the next date gave a 0 again so i want to get the first date that gave the first 0 after the date where it gave a more than 0 value..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your table exactly looks like but you can use the max function. Basically, something like this:

```
select max(date) where ([Value1] <= 0 OR [Value2] <= 0 OR [Value3] <= 0)
```

Comment: what if there is a new data send and the data is still 0 so with this query it will get the latest again but what i want to do is if the new data is still 0 the date that will be get is the last data when it became 0 not to newest.

Comment: @Carl can you share some data and its  output

Comment: @carl your dbms sql server？

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should have the parentheses

```
WHERE ( [Value1] <= 0 OR [Value2] <= 0 OR [Value3] <= 0 ) AND [DATE_TIME] >= [DATE_TIME]
```

Comment: Though this might be all OP is missing, without some sample data, we don't know if this query is correct or not. If there are 10 dates in a row where all of the values are `0`, your query will simply grab the most recent one, whereas the *earliest* of those 10 dates would be when the value *became* 0.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table onto itself and then calculate when a change happens. In the example below, it uses ID and assumes that ID is always just incrementing by 1, you could do this with ROW_NUMBER if you don't have a guaranteed increase value (e.g. even if  you have an identity column, someone could delete a record).

```
CREATE TABLE sampleData
(
    id          INT            IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,RecordDate DATETIME       NOT NULL
    ,value      DECIMAL(18, 6) NOT NULL
)


INSERT INTO sampleData (RecordDate, value)
VALUES
('2018-07-26 21:00', 2)
,('2018-07-26 22:00', 0)
,('2018-07-26 23:00', 0)
,('2018-07-27 00:00', 0)
,('2018-07-27 01:00', 0);

WITH FindWhenRecordChanges AS
(
    SELECT      primarySampleData.*
                ,CASE
                     WHEN   primarySampleData.value = 0
                      AND   joinedSampleData.value <> 0 THEN
                         1
                     ELSE
                         0
                 END AS recordChanged
    FROM        sampleData AS primarySampleData
    LEFT JOIN   sampleData AS joinedSampleData
           ON   joinedSampleData.id + 1 = primarySampleData.id
)
SELECT  MAX(FindWhenRecordChanges.RecordDate)
FROM    FindWhenRecordChanges
WHERE   FindWhenRecordChanges.recordChanged = 1
```

Comment: its  complicated for me i cant understand how can I do this in my sql query. but this queary is working when i use sql fiddle. I just dont know how will i do this query in my database. sorry I am really not good in sql syntaxes

Comment: You need to find when the data changed, so you need to join the table back onto itself so you get 2 records - the old value and the new value

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with a not exists. Not clear from your description what happens if the values moves from zero to something else and back?

This one finds the first time it went to zero assuming its still at zero.

For example, if the zero is a stock quantity then it finds when did we run out. And doesnt find anything is we have later restocked.

```
select min(date) as found_date from tab 
where value=0
and not exists(select * from tab t2 where t2.date>tab.date)
```

Answer (score -1):

According to sample data Your query was almost right just order in `ASC`

```
    select Top 1 * from 
    (

       SELECT      primarySampleData.*
                ,CASE
                     WHEN   primarySampleData.value = 0
                      AND   joinedSampleData.value <> 0 THEN
                         1
                     ELSE
                         0
                 END AS recordChanged
    FROM        sampleData AS primarySampleData
    LEFT JOIN   sampleData AS joinedSampleData
           ON   joinedSampleData.id + 1 = primarySampleData.id
           ) as T

           where recordChanged =1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5a46b/1 go this link i created a sample for you

Comment: it give the latest date that gave the 0 value... i want to get the date where it gave the first 0 value not the latest

Comment: Edited my answer